# How can I use my data from a JSON string to populate dimple d3.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts, dimple.js

My objective is to get data from database and use it to populate a dimple js line chart.
I am using JSON to carry the data from back-end. Below is the code from my servlet going to http request/respose.

```
String sql2 = "select a,date from table order by date";
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
DataDAOImpl rdao = new DataDAOImpl();
list = rdao.getData(sql2);
req.setAttribute("line", list.toJSONString());
WebUtil.forward(req, resp, this, "/test/linechart.jsp");
```

And my code in jsp is as below. It is inside a javascript tag. The chart is not rendering although the data is available in JSP. Also this is running on local web server. Please advice what I am missing. I have to generate several reports and this is my proof of concept.

```
//script type="text/javascript">

var data = '${line}';
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.setBounds(100, 200, 505, 305);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "date");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "a");
chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();

///script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried `JSON.parse('${line}');`?

I'm not familiar with your exact case but I believe that will turn a string containing JSON into JSON.  Is there any console error?

Comment: yes, i discover this function this morning and tried. It worked beautifully! thanks though. Do you know the command to increase the line thickness in dimple API line chart?

Comment: var s = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line); s.lineWeight = 10; Here's an example: http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color